# How to display date selected from blade to blade?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, eloquent

I have a form in my blade with 2 dates for user to select like:

```html
<form role="form" action="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\PreBuiltController@viewgraphByDate', [$companyID])}}" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div class="form-group-attached">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default required" >
          <label>From</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="from" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default required" >
          <label>To</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <button class="btn alt-btn-black btn-sm alt-btn pull-right" type="submit">Filter Date</button>
</form>
```

So in my controller function I have did this:

```
$dateFrom = [$request->from];
$dateTo = [$request->to];
```

Then I tried to `dd();` the value of `datefrom` and `dateto` and I am able to show it, but now I want to know how can I display this 2 values back in my blade file?

In my return view I have `compact()` the 2 values also.

Comment: what happens when you `dd($request->all())`? better yet throw it into the log with `Log::debug(json_encode($request->all()))` once you put `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;` in the head.

Comment: @developernator it returns `array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "g3zidwHzadOludiXTLUHhBxqguPhY7gRdM9hYL1y"
  "from" => "2018-01-04"
  "to" => "2018-03-15"
]`

Comment: great, that means the data is getting the received.

Comment: you should be able to do `$from = $request->from;`

Answer (score 1):

you can use laravel form model binding to show selected values in laravel blade.

or

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" value="{{$to}}" required>
```

here $to is your returning date from controller to view in compact

Comment: $dateFrom = $request->from;
    $dateTo = $request->to;
    // dd($dateFrom, $dateTo);

    return view('AltHr.Chatbot.viewgraph', compact('companyID','match','noAnswer','missing','email','pdf','image','video','text','totalMedia','dateFrom','dateTo'));
  }

Comment: <input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" value="{{$dateTo}}" required>

Answer (score 1):

Firstly use Carbon in your Controller

```
   use Carbon\Carbon;
```

then do this in your blade file

```
   <input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" value="{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($dateFrom)}}" required>
```

you can also format the date if you like to

```
   <input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" value="{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($dateFrom)->format('Y-m-d))}}" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and update your output method from the comment from the post above to:

...

```
$dateFrom = $request->from;
$dateTo = $request->to;

$data = [
    'companyID' => $companyID,
    'match' => $match,
    'noAnswer' => $noAnswer,
    'missing' => $missing,
    'email' => $email,
    'pdf' => $pdf,
    'image' => $image,
    'video' => $video,
    'text' => $text,
    'totalMedia' => $totalMedia,
    'dateFrom' => $dateFrom,
    'dateTo' => $dateTo
];

return view('AltHr.Chatbot.viewgraph', $data);
```

...

Since you stated this is live loading the request to the page you may want to add 

`$request->flash();`
 
to top beginning of the receiving method.

Comment: {{ dateFrom }} and {{ dateTo }}

Comment: what i mean is how can i return it on the same page? because now the function is on Page A and once funtion execute it will return to Page A again

Comment: Use the old() helper https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-old and https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input